# x86 ASM question about hexadecimal numbers and how to transfer them

Tags: assembly, hexadecimal

So I am wondering why I cannot do this

```
mov eax, ffffffffh
```

but I can do this:

```
mov eax, 0ffffffffh
```

Could anybody explain please? In this case, I am using the Flat Assembler but I think this is not assembler-specific.

Answer (score 4):

Most assemblers require numeric constants to begin with a digit, this is so they can distinguish between them and labels.

You can see it in [*FASM Fundamental syntax rules*](https://flatassembler.net/docs.php?article=fasmg_manual#1):

> Numbers are distinguished from names by the fact that they either
>   begin with a decimal digit, or with the "$" character followed by any
>   hexadecimal digit. This means that a token can be considered numeric
>   even when it is not a valid number. To be a correct one it must be one
>   of the following: a decimal number (optionally with the letter "d"
>   attached at the end), a binary number followed by the letter "b", an
>   octal number followed by the letter "o" or "q", or a hexadecimal
>   number either prepended with "$" or "0x", or followed by the character
>   "h". Because the first digit of a hexadecimal number can be a letter,
>   it may be needed to prepend it with the digit zero in order to make it
>   recognizable as a number. For example, "0Ah" is a valid number, while
>   "Ah" is just a name.

and in [MASM Manual](http://people.sju.edu/~ggrevera/arch/references/MASM61PROGUIDE.pdf) as well:

> Hexadecimal numbers must always start with a decimal digit (0–9). If
>   necessary, add a leading zero to distinguish between symbols and
>   hexadecimal numbers that start with a letter.

Looking at `0ffffffffh` you can see 8 significant hex digits, exactly as you'd expect. This is not unique to `0ffffffffh`, another numeric literals should be written with a leading zero as well --  `0d1h`, `0aah`, `0b0h`.

These days it is common for assemblers to support the `0xffffffff` syntax. If yours is not (FLAT supports it), make sure to pay attention to the leading zero, otherwise the hexadecimal value would be interpreted as a label or another symbol name.